# Common security practices when an app reads/writes an encrypted database file

Tags: security, encryption

I'm writing an app that needs to read/write important datas from/to an encrypted local database file.

What are the best practices to ensure a great level of security while performing the following tasks?

1) **Read the database while asking the password only once**: right now when started the program asks to the user the password needed to decrypt the database, then it decrypts and reads the database and assign a clear version of it to a variable for future readings and manipulations. I know that while a program doesn't use swap memory its variables should not be accessible by other processes, but **is there a way to make it more secure?**

2) **Write a modified version of the encrypted database without asking the password again**: right now once the user provides the password to decrypt the database the app saves the password to a local variable so that it could write a modified, encrypted, version of the database to a file. **Is there a way to do the same without saving the password in a clear form?** I thought that I could simply use an hash of the password as the key for encryption/decryption, but still I would need to assign the hashed version of the password to a variable, and I would like to do it better.

Thank you all.